# The change on the code not reflected with React Native

Tags: react-native

I am developing a simple chat program with react native for learning purpose (not use expo). I made changes with the chat message (along with other code change) and was trying to reload the new message with USB debugging on Android device. But the app persistently shows the old message before change. Here is what I did:

1. Under android subdir, run `.\gradlew clean`
2. close android studio and `react-native run-android` again
3. Shake the device and choose `reload`

The #3 causes the error below:

[image]

Is there some module like `nodemon` for `nodejs` which picks up the code change nice and easily?

Comment: Check terminal. I guess there is some syntax error in code and its not loading new bundle.

Comment: There is an error on the terminal: Could not run adb reverse: Command failed: c:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk/platform-tools/adb -s LGD851d72f302ab reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081.

Comment: Try this `adb kill-server && adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: Same error (could not run adb reverse....). I deleted the app from the device and is still show the old message. Ran `native-react start --reset-cache` and no help. Somehow the old copy is very sticky. However test on a newer version device (8 vs 4.4) works fine with changes.Not sure what caused the stickiness on the older android version device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I often get this issue too. In this situation, I turn off the debug mode, and run `adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081 && react-native run-android` again.

Answer (score 1):

Connect your phone to your wifi, and try this,

1. Trigger the `Developer Menu`
2. Go to `Dev Settings` > `Debug server host & port for device`
3. Set it to `<your_pc_ip_address_on_local_wifi>:8081`. (If you are on a emulator, set it to `localhost:8081`)
4. Restart the app